# Segmentation fault when reassign the map value

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, undefined-behavior

The following code behaves different on different environments.

On

```
 c++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

the assignment in constructor of B will fill `aptr_` with value `std::shared_ptr<A> (empty) = {get() = 0x0}`, which leads to the Segmentation fault when reading `s` from `a`.

But on

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.5.0 20171010 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04)
```

the code works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
  A(string s)
  {
    s_ = s;
  }
  string s_;
};
using APtr = shared_ptr<A>;
class B
{
public:
  map<string, APtr> aptr_;
  B()
  {
    aptr_["1"] = getA("1");
    aptr_["2"] = getA("2");
  };
  APtr getA(const std::string &s)
  {
    if (aptr_.find(s) != aptr_.end())
    {
      return aptr_[s];
    }
    else
    {
      aptr_[s] = APtr(new A(s));
      return aptr_[s];
    }
  };
};
int main()
{
  auto b=B();
  auto a=b.getA("1");
  cout<<a->s_<<endl;
}
```

I think this may involve some undefined behavior.So what specific undefined behavior is this?

Comment: *Why is that?* -- Ask yourself if the code you have is actually undefined behavior.  If the answer is "yes", then anything can happen, and it then becomes a moot point as to why undefined behavior is what it is.

Comment: I understand this involves some undefined behavior. I want to know what specific undefined behavior it is.

Comment: understand that after the first line `return aptr_[s];` in `getA` no code below that ever executes.

Comment: @yano sorry about the mistake, I just notice the mistake, the code has been updated.

Comment: *I want to know what specific undefined behavior it is* -- That will be like the dog trying to catch its own tail.  What if in an update of the compiler, something else happens?  Are you going to investigate that also?  Trying to have you not waste too much time on a moving target.

Comment: The comment section is for comments, not answers.  The main comment I have is that undefined behavior can be anything, including things "working".  You avoid it by recognizing what it is and thus never write code in that way.  Don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: You already wrote in the question the undefined behavior, reading `s` from `a` when `a.get() == 0x0`.